# How to organize Cmake file properly for the many source and headers?

Tags: c++, cmake

I know this question has been asked many times. I have checked them but I am a newbie on CMake. Thus I could not figure out how to solve the problem.

My file organization like this;

```
e0
|-CMakeLists.txt
|-grade.cpp
|-median.cpp
|-student_info.cpp
|-main.cpp
|-include
  |-grade.h
  |-median.h
  |-student_info.h
```

My CMakeLists.txt file as shown below.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project(E0)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
include_directories(headers)
add_executable(E0 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(E0 headers)
```

When I run make, I have faced up

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lheaders
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/E0.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'E0' failed make[2]: *** 
[E0] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/E0.dir/all' 
failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/E0.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Could you help me, how to write CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: `target_link_libraries` should only be used to link to libraries (dynamic or static) and other CMake targets. Just remove that line. You should definitely add the other `.cpp` files to your `add_executable` statement so that code is actually compiled, though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `CMakeLists.txt` should look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project(E0)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp grade.cpp median.cpp student_info.cpp)
include_directories(include)
add_executable(E0 ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

You really should read documentation instead of putting random statements into your file.

Comment: Could you advice a documentation to learn cmake ?